# My money plant is dieing out. Please help!

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants

I have got the money plant as a Christmas gift last year on 2018. It was indoor till October 2019 at my office window. i used to take care of it, watering whenever required. but post October month it started dieing.

I brought it to my house and transferred to beer bottles with only water in it. But nothing changed them.

Then again I transfered it to a pot, put in soil and started watering regularly whenever required. Their condition worsens. I have kept them indoor again. Untill then it was under sun. Please help how i can make it as it was earlier.

unable to attach photo.
1. no leaves now
2. stems have almost died. 2 are green others are yellow, like died. 
3.3 or 4 single stem plant in one earthen pot
4. since beginning the plant was together with 5 or 6 stems. while transferring gave away few stems to my friends. 
[image]

Comment: 'gave away a few stems' - how did you remove these stems - did you break apart the rootball? Did you put it in a pot with drainage holes in the bottom, and what soil did you use in the  pot - sterllised potting soil, soil from the garden? What part of the world are you in, and how long was the plant outdoors, and how long has it been indoors since you moved it inside? We really need a photo....

Comment: @Bamboo gave away a few stems' - how did you remove these stems - did you break apart the rootball? please see my plant image. they are separate while unrooting them to bring from my office I gave 1 stem to my colleague. I didn't break any roots or stems. Did you put it in a pot with drainage holes in the bottom - yes all my plant pots have drainage system underneath. This is now in an earthen pot with holes at the bottom. I have used soil from the garden and the rest of my plants are using the same soil.

Comment: @Bamboo What part of the world are you in, and how long was the plant outdoors, and how long has it been indoors since you moved it inside? I belong to India, in Delhi where currently the temperature is between 18-25 degrees celsius. While transferring I kept my plant outdoors, openly under the sun, this must be one month now and now for 2 weeks, I kept it inside, regularly watering as needed. I again shifted it to my balcony but it is in partial shade.

Answer (score 1):

The temperature and humidity at your office might have changed or the plant has gone dormant

The amount of water used should be decreased when the plant is dormant as they use less water and the colder weather keeps the soil hydrated for longer. 
There are different types of “money plant”

[image]

[image: Miniature Variety Of Jade Plant]

[image: ‘Gollum’ Variety Of Jade Plant]

But one thing they all have in common is the temperature range they prefer/require.

18C - 26C 
As well as higher range/levels of humidity

Plants love environment stability as they are forced to change their body’s to fit the environment.

Sometimes they adapt/change their genetic expression one way at the cost of not being able to reverse the changes easily.

Comment: that makes sense as its currently winter